# Why I have a loop in my react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm making my application to test the library but I've got a strange loop and I don't figure out where does it come from.

My code :

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation";
import axios from "axios";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import {randomNumber} from "../components/_helper";

const Home = () => { 
    console.log('coucou')

    const [randomCharacters, setRandomCharacters] = useState([]);
    const [totalCharacters, setTotalCharacters] = useState('');
    const [randomNumbers, setRandomNumbers] = useState('');


    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
            .then((response) => {
                setTotalCharacters(response.data.info.count)
            })
    })

    useEffect(() =>{
        axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1,23,45,654,21,12')
            .then((response) => {
                response.data.map(() => (
                    setRandomCharacters(response.data)
                ))
            })
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation/>
            {randomCharacters.map( (character) => (
                <Card key={character.id} character={character}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

As you can see, I did a console.log at the beginning of my code and I have no loop writing (for, foreach) but this is what happen in the console :

[image: result from the console]

I don't understand this behavior, someone to explain where I did wrong ?

Comment: You have not provided a [dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) to either of your `useEffect`s so they run on every render, then they setState which triggers a render, etc, etc. If you only want your fetches to run on the first render add an empty dependency array. `useEffect(() =>{ axios.get(  ... }, [])`

Comment: the function runs every time your component renders, so there should be no surprise that statements like your `console.log` in the body execute multiple times. Your only issue here, although it's a serious one, is the one @pilchard points out, which means you have unnecessary API requests running more or less continually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2 `useEffect`s run every time when re-render occurs.

In your `useEffect`, you update state variables `randomCharacters` and `totalCharacters`. Then re-render occurs whenever your APIs return different data because of these state updates.

So your app loops infinitely.

At least you need to add one more dependency. But in your case, you can pass empty dependency `[]` for one time API call.

> Here is a tip from React official document. If you want to run an
> effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass
> an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your
> effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never
> needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows
> directly from how the dependencies array always works.

**Code should look like the following:**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
            .then((response) => {
                setTotalCharacters(response.data.info.count)
            })
    }, [])

useEffect(() =>{
        
    axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1,23,45,654,21,12')
            .then((response) => {
                response.data.map(() => (
                    setRandomCharacters(response.data)
                ))
            })
    }, [])
```